Visual Studio can't start containerized ASP.NET Core if Docker HealthChecks present whilst debugging
I'm building 2 ASP.NET Core Web API services containerized with Docker, WebApplication1 and WebApplication2. WebApplication2 depends on WebApplication1 that is why in WebApplication1, I have an endpoint exposed for the HealthCheck that docker compose will implement for WebApplication1:
using System.Net;    

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();

var containerInfo = app.MapGroup("/health1");
containerInfo.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) =>
{
    return HttpStatusCode.OK;
});

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

With Dockerfile
 # This stage is used when running from VS in fast mode (Default for Debug configuration)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:9.0-preview AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
USER app

# This stage is used to build the service project
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:9.0-preview AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# This stage is used to publish the service project to be copied to the final stage
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./WebApplication1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# This stage is used in production or when running from VS in regular mode (Default when not using the Debug configuration)
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]

Startup code and Dockerfile for WebApplication2 is exactly the same. This is the Docker Compose file:
  services:
  webapplication1:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplication1
    build:
      context: WebApplication1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8080      
    ports:
      - 53661:8080
      - 53662:8081
    healthcheck:         
        test: curl http://localhost:8080/health1 || exit 1              
        start_period: 10s
        start_interval: 10s
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 20s
        retries: 5 
  webapplication2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplication2
    build:
      context: WebApplication2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8080
    depends_on:
        webapplication1:    
          condition: service_healthy 
    ports:
      - 63661:8080
      - 63662:8081

Notice this line test: curl http://localhost:8080/health1 || exit 1 is the code that should be marking WebApplication1 as healthy so WebApplication2 can start. When I debug the docker compose orchestration, it fails:
3>#12 [webapplication2] resolving provenance for metadata file
3>#12 DONE 0.0s
3> Container WebApplication1  Creating
3> Container WebApplication1  Created
3> Container WebApplication2  Creating
3> Container WebApplication2  Created
3> Container WebApplication1  Starting
3> Container WebApplication1  Started
3> Container WebApplication1  Waiting
3> Container WebApplication1  Error
3>dependency failed to start: container WebApplication1 is unhealthy
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(430,5): error DT1001: dependency failed to start: container WebApplication1 is unhealthy
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(430,5): error DT1001: If the error persists, try restarting Docker Desktop.
3>Done building project "docker-compose.dcproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 07:48 and took 36.168 seconds ==========


Running
docker inspect WebApplication1 --format  '{{range .State.Health.Log}}{{.End}} | Exit Code: {{.ExitCode}} | {{.Output}}{{end}}'

results in this error:

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

I placed a breakpoint in Program.cs from WebApplication1 and it doesn't get started under this configuration, but if I comment the healthcheck code from the compose file it works as expected. Weirdly enough if I do a docker compose up --build, it works properly

My first thoughts were that should be something with the Visual Studio Docker tools configuration in Debug mode, it was suggested in other StackOverFlow posts to add this:
<PropertyGroup>
    <ContainerDevelopmentMode>Regular</ContainerDevelopmentMode>
</PropertyGroup>

But doesn't work either. Any ideas what is going wrong with the health checks?
I attach a working .zip file with the solution so it can be easily tested
Thanks!

Please try running it without breakpoints. If you have a breakpoint, execution will stop at the breakpoint and the healthcheck code never responds.

What I meant is that the HealthChecks never allow the code to run, it doesn't matter if there is a breakpoint or not. The healtchecks seem to block the entrypoint of WebApplication1 and the var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); never gets called.

The issue you're encountering might be due to curl trying to access localhost within the health check container itself. In Docker Compose, localhost refers to the container running the health check, not the service containers. You should modify the health check configuration to use the service name webapplication1 instead of localhost.

Hi, just tried that but didn't work either. In any case, the localhost curl healthcheck works fine while the solution is being ran in release with docker compose up --build so it should work with localhost also in Debug, but thanks for another view on it.

For the benefit of anyone finding this in search. The Visual Studio Compose debugging experience currently doesn't support dependencies. Fixing this is being tracked here: Visual Studio can't start containerized ASP.NET Core if Docker HealthChecks present whilst debugging
